# How to perform an updateItem operation with a JSON payload on a Dynamo DB table

Tags: java, json, amazon-dynamodb

The Dynamo DB document API allows put operation using a json payload

```
Item item = Item.fromJSON(payload);
table.putItem(item);
```

However I couldn't find a similar way for performing an updateItem with a Json payload.

Is there a Dynamo DB support for that?

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish? is there a reason not to call `putItem` again?

Comment: my understanding and observation is that putItem would overwrite the entire item. This is not desired as the update payload that I have doesn't have all the members which the existing record has. This in-effect leads to loss of those members if I put again.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a snippet as to how you would do it in Javascript.

```js
let updateExpression = 'SET ';
let expressionAttributeValues = {};

const keys = Object.keys(payload);
for (const key of keys) {
  updateExpression += `${key}=:${key},`;
  expressionAttributeValues[`:${key}`] = payload[key];
}
updateExpression=updateExpression.slice(0,-1);

let params = {  
  TableName : 'your_table_name',
  Key: {
    id: id
  }, 
  UpdateExpression : updateExpression,
  ExpressionAttributeValues : expressionAttributeValues,
  ReturnValues: "ALL_NEW"
}

db.update(params,(err, result)=>{});
```

Comment: careful of reserved words like "name",
ExpressionAttributeNames should be used somehow

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with this for a while in the end you have to use a map.

```
UpdateItemOutcome updateItemOutcome = table.updateItem(
                new UpdateItemSpec()
                        .withPrimaryKey("id", "yourId")                            
                        .withUpdateExpression("SET document.field = :field")
                        .withValueMap(new ValueMap()
                                        .withMap(":field", "map of key value pairs that will get serialized to json")));
```

Answer (score 0):

The UpdateItemSpec currently doesn't accept Item as input -- you will have to parse the json content first (presumably via Item.fromJSON) and then use either AttributeUpdate or UpdateExpression to specify the update action on each individual field (SET, ADD etc.)

Here is the documentation to using UpdateExpression to update an item http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/JavaDocumentAPIItemCRUD.html#JavaDocumentAPIItemUpdate

Comment: I'm parsing the JSON tree by reading each top-level attribute as "Object" and then using that value to create an AttributeUpdate.

However, is there a particular reason why putItem supports a from JSON operation and updateItem doesn't?